# Dynamic operators within DAGs

Tags: python, airflow

I would like to know if what I did to achieve to goal of dynamic operators within an Airflow DAG is a good or a bad practice.

> The goal I had to achieve was to create a 'x' amount of operators within
>   a DAG based on the result of an API call. This DAG will run every for example every week.

The program that I made works, but I don't know if it is a good practice for developing DAGs for Airflow. So my question is: is it a good practice or if not what would be a better solution to this problem?

The code I used to achieve this goal:

```
with DAG('my_dag', default_args=default_args, schedule_interval='@weekly') as my_dag:

    start = DummyOperator(
        task_id='start'
    )

    endpoint = 'www.example.com/api/dummies'
    r = requests.get(endpoint)
    dummies = r.json()

   for _, dummy in enumerate(dummies):
        dummy_operator = DummyOperator(
                    task_id='dummy_opr_{}'.format(dummy['id']
                    )
        start >> dummy_operator
```

Comment: You're probably better off posting this to [the code review StackExchange site](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). This kind of question would fit right in.

Comment: Thanks. Will ask the question over there aswell!

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, "Yes" it is indeed a common pattern to create such tasks dynamically.